# How to deal with canvas（which in the my customView that in another java class） in an activity？

Tags: java, android, canvas

This method is in my CustomView but I want to use this method depending on
activity's rssi(Integer var).

```
public void pointPaint(int rssi,Canvas canvas,Paint paint){

        Resources r = getResources();
        Bitmap bp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.component_radar_light_point);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bp, 320, 480, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bp, 240, 130, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bp, 170, 220, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bp, 180, 100, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bp, 460, 400, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bp, 200, 249, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bp, 316, 210, paint);
    }
```

when I use

```
customViewByMySelf.pointPaint(rssi,customViewByMySelf.getCustomCanvas(),customViewByMySelf.getCustomPaint());
```

that reports `NullPointerException`

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)' on a null object reference at tools.CustomViewByMySelf.pointPaint(CustomViewByMySelf.java:138)

Comment: you should post more code about where the function has been called and all.